# Is there any way in Airtime to set up some tracks as spots/ads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, icecast, internet-radio

I'm not using Airtime Sourcefabric, but one of my clients do.

I'm working on the radio station's website, and found out that my client has some short "spots" between EACH song.

You can check the WIP site here: http://wickedradionet.com/new/

Below the slider, there is a dark gray line showing the current show's title, and below, the previous, the current and the next track. My problem is that the previous and next titles are not really songs, but short radio spots, for example: "You currently listening to XY show on Wicked Radio.".

I just want to know if there is any way to let Airtime know that these are not songs, so not put these titles to the list here: http://music.wickedradionet.com/api/live-info

Don't know if it's even possible, but I appreciate any suggestions from someone who has a little knowledge about IceCast. Thanks in advice!

Comment: Looks like that station is using Airtime. You should check with them, as that's not an Icecast, but Airtime API. Also please note it's Icecast, not IceCast.

Comment: I've corrected my question...